# Magento-Adobe Acquisition - What does it mean for the community version?

Tags: magento2

Any idea of how the Magento-Adobe acquisition will affect the developers or the community version in general?

Comment: check this tweet https://twitter.com/mjasay/status/998930665805496321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question may be more relevant elsewhere, there has been similar concerns raised through out the community. A good read on what Adobe's view point on keeping Magento open source/CE is https://medium.com/@5bf90f4ff4fa/c9f8246e83e2 while it doesn't offer specific examples of **how** but I would anticipate more rolling in of Adobe's cloud services & more front end tech like nodejs.